# Signalling where a new row should start based on arbitrary characters when converting webscraped output to a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp, stringr

I'm scraping a television script and then trying to clean it up. This is what I have so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

s1_e1 <- read_html('http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/27-1.htm')

s1_e1 <- s1_e1 %>%
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  html_text() 

s1_e1 <- str_replace_all(string = s1_e1, pattern = "\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)", replacement = "")
s1_e1 <- str_replace_all(string = s1_e1, pattern = "\\s*\\[[^\\]]+\\]", replacement = "") 
s1_e1 <- str_squish(s1_e1)

s1_e1 <- s1_e1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(value!="") %>% 
  mutate(season = "27",
         episode_num = "1",
         airdate_orig = str_sub(.$value[1], -12),
         episode_name = str_sub(.$value[1], 1, regexpr(" O", .$value[1])-1)) %>% 
  slice(-1)
```

Which gives me the below:

```
# A tibble: 38 x 5
   value                                    season episode_num airdate_orig episode_name
   <chr>                                    <chr>  <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       
 1 ROSE: Bye! JACKIE: See you later!        27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 2 TANNOY: This is a customer announcement… 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 3 ROSE: You pulled his arm off. DOCTOR: Y… 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 4 ROSE: That's just not funny. That's sic… 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 5 TAXI DRIVER: Watch it!                   27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 6 TELEVISION: The whole of Central London… 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 7 JACKIE: There's no point in getting up,… 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 8 JACKIE: There's Finch's. You could try … 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 9 ROSE: It's about last night. He's part … 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
10 ROSE: Don't mind the mess. Do you want … 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
# … with 28 more rows
```

I would like each row to be a new character's speech. As you can see, thankfully the script capitalizes who is speaking and then has a colon and a space before new speech, i.e. `ROSE:`  or `TANNOY:` . Is there a way to indicate to R that I want each row of the tibble to begin with this capitalized text followed by a colon and to continue in that row until there is another capitalized word followed by a colon?

For example, the first row would start with `ROSE: Bye!` and the second row would start with `JACKIE: See you later!`, the third `TANNOY: This is a customer announcement…` until it reached another capitalized word followed by a colon, and so on.

Additionally, if anyone has any suggestions for how I can integrate the stringr functions into the dplyr chunk let me know. I can make a separate post about this if that's best, but I kept getting errors when attempting to do that (the above is functional though).

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Look-ahead pattern:

```r
library(tidyverse)

s1_e1 %>% 
  mutate(value=str_split(value, "\\s(?=[A-Z]+:)")) %>% 
  unnest(value)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 322 x 5
   value                                                             season episode_num airdate_orig episode_name
   <chr>                                                             <chr>  <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       
 1 ROSE: Bye!                                                        27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 2 JACKIE: See you later!                                            27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 3 TANNOY: This is a customer announcement. The store will be closi~ 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 4 GUARD: Oi!                                                        27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 5 ROSE: Wilson? Wilson, I've got the lottery money. Wilson, are yo~ 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 6 ROSE: I can't hang about 'cos they're closing the shop. Wilson! ~ 27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 7 ROSE: Hello? Hello, Wilson, it's Rose. Hello? Wilson?             27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 8 ROSE: Wilson? Wilson!                                             27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
 9 ROSE: You're kidding me.                                          27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose        
10 ROSE: Is that someone mucking about? Who is it?                   27     1           26 Mar, 2005 Rose
```

### Simplified workflow

You can indeed put all your operations into one pipe:

```r
s1_e1 <- read_html('http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/27-1.htm') %>%
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  tibble(value = .) %>% 
  mutate(value = str_squish(str_replace_all(value, "(\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)|\\s*\\[[^\\]]+\\])", ""))) %>% 
  filter(value!="") %>% 
  mutate(season = "27",
         episode_num = "1",
         airdate_orig = str_sub(.$value[1], -12),
         episode_name = str_sub(.$value[1], 1, regexpr(" O", .$value[1])-1)) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  mutate(value=str_split(value, "\\s(?=[A-Z]+:)")) %>% 
  unnest(value)
```

Comment: Just being curious: Why is your tibble named `s1_e1` if this is season 27?

Comment: It's a good question. As i'm sure you've surmised i'm doing some text analysis of Doctor Who screenplays and am starting with 'New Who' (so the seasons beginning in 2005 with Christopher Eccleston). Season 1 of New Who is actually season 27 of the broader Who catalogue (may change that when I bring in the older seasons)

Comment: Quick follow up on the code. If I want to extract the speaker, I can pipe the above into `mutate(character = str_sub(.$value, 1, regexpr(":", .$value)-1))`, but how do I then remove the speaker from the `value` column? I tried adding `value = str_sub(.$value, -regexpr(": ", .$value)-1)` into the `mutate` but that yields unexpected results

Comment: I would try something like: `s1_e1 %>% mutate(character = str_extract(value, "^([A-Z]+)(?=:\\s)"), value = str_remove(value, "^([A-Z]+:\\s)"))`.